# JBoss 7.1.1 JVM monitoring using SNMP and PRTG

Tags: java, jboss, jvm, snmp, prtg

Recently I had given task in my company to monitor JVM of JBoss application server 7.1.1 using PRTG on Windows plateform. After searching I came to know to monitor using PRTG snmp enabling is required. JVM starts and listen on specified port and PRTG communicates using snmp to get the jvm information like heap , non heap , thread etc information.

---

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, I followed these steps:

Configured Jboss to start with snmp agent enabled.
Added following lines in `standalone.conf.bat`

> set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.management.snmp.port=1161 -Dcom.sun.management.snmp.interface=0.0.0.0 -Dcom.sun.management.snmp.acl=false"

That was giving me error of LogManager on start up.To resolve this I have added following lines in the same file.

> set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS%
>   -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,org.jboss.logmanager -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -Xbootclasspath/p:%JBOSS_HOME%\jboss-logmanager-1.2.2.GA.jar;%JBOSS_HOME%\jboss-logmanager-log4j-1.0.0.GA.jar;%JBOSS_HOME%\log4j-1.2.16.jar"

That solved my problem and the server started successfully.

For testing connection I have used following command.

> snmpwalk -v2c -c public 127.0.0.1:1161 
>   SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.42.2.145.3.163.1.1.4

PRTG configuration was done by system administrator. :-)